# Crystal Reports Export Access Denied

Tags: crystal-reports

I am maintaining some code that uses CR to create a report and write it to disk.

```
var report = new ReportDocument();
....
report.Export();
```

On our live server this is resulting in the following error:

```
Error in File E:\TEMP\temp_cb1a18c2-b4e6-46b8-901b-a7a028a43b79.rpt: Access to report file denied. Another program may be using it.
```

The app is running as Network Service and has full control of the e:\temp diretory so it seems strange to be getting an access denied message.

Anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably have to see more of your code. Are you loading a report from disk with ReportDocument.Load, with OpenReportByTempCopy specified?